# Merton's Problem Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Solve the following numerical case of Merton's optimal portfolio selection problem: find an
optimal policy function $(s, y) \mapsto u(s, y)$ such that for the Ito diusion determined by $dX_t =X_t(u(t, Xt) + 1)dt + 4u(t, Xt)X_tdB_t, X_0 = 1$, the expectation $E^{0,1}[(X_3)^{\frac{1}{2}}$] is maximal.

Could anyone please explain me how I could solve this using the Bellman equation in continuous time? ( $-W_t = \sup_{v \in V}\left[ f(t,x,v) + u(t,x,v)W_x + \frac{1}{2}\Sigma^2W_{xx} \right] $ )

Comment: @ JanR : As the solution is given I would go for a  verification theorem approach. Best  regards.

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you for your help. The solution isn't given, is it? And could you show me how I should go about doing that then, because I cannot seem to get any further with this question?